# Сервис независимый от приложения

Tags: android, android-service

Если создать самый простой сервис, допустим, воспроизводящий музыку, то при закрытии приложения сервис остановится. Как сделать сервис независимый от приложения, что бы продолжал работать и после закрытия приложения.

Answer (score 2):

Для относительной независимости достаточно в манифесте добавить строку

```
<service
     .....
     android:process=":service"
>
</service>
```

При этом, при закрытии всех активити (и даже "смахивании" их из списка запущенных) сервис будет работать. Запускать сервис при этом следует примерно так:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ....
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Однако всё это не спасёт если приложении будет закрыто через `kill pid` (например через настройки -> приложение).

Данная тема достаточно серьёзная, некоторые вещи зависят от API и прошивки устройства.

Пишите если забыл ещё что-то важное.